# Android Firebase query not executing onChildAdded

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently I have a problem with a Firebase query that is not executing the `onChildAdded` method. I implemented a callback to handle the asynchronous nature of Firebase queries, therefore, after having populated the`sectoresMayorEspera` and `localizacionMayorEspera` ArrayLists inside the `onChildAdded` method using data contained in the `dataSnapshot`, the `buscarEspera` method should be executed with the previous ArrayLists as parameters.

The problem arises when `onChildAdded` method is "ignored" and the `buscarEspera` method is passed empty ArrayLists.

```
    public void busquedaEspera(final MiCallbackEspera miCallbackEspera) {

    if (cantidadBuses > 1) {
        Firebase sectoresMasTiempo = new Firebase("https://brilliant-heat-7882.firebaseio.com/SectoresDatos/").child(String.valueOf(sectorOrigenBus));
        sectoresMasTiempo.orderByChild("espera").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                sectoresMayorEspera.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                HashMap hashMap = (HashMap) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                HashMap localizacionHashMap = (HashMap) hashMap.get("localizacionEspera");
                localizacionMayorEspera.add(new LatLng((double) localizacionHashMap.get("latitude"), (double) localizacionHashMap.get("longitude")));
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });

        miCallbackEspera.buscarEspera(sectoresMayorEspera, localizacionMayorEspera);
    }
```

I am new to coding (obviously new to Android, to Java, to...) I'd appreciate your help to tackle this one.

Comment: The `onChildAdded` method will be triggered after your call to `miCallbackEspera.buscarEspera`. See this question where I wrote up how to either work around this or, preferably, how to properly use it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener/33204705#33204705

Comment: Thank you very much Frank, the question you pointed out was extremely helpful, placing the callback method inside the onChildAdded method besides some other refactoring to properly work with the ArrayLists as they update saved me from drowning, you truly have to "embrace" the asynchronous character of Firebase if  you pretend to succeed working with it.

Comment: You're taking the red pill? Awesome!